# How to have a dynamic path for the string in C#?

Tags: c#, file

```cs
private static void clearFolderWithFilter(string folderName = @"C:\A\B" , string filesToExclude = "debug.log")
{
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(folderName);

    foreach (FileInfo fi in dir.GetFiles())
    {
        if (!fi.Name.Contains(filesToExclude))
        {
            fi.Delete();
        }
    }

    foreach (DirectoryInfo di in dir.GetDirectories())
    {
        if (!di.Name.Contains(filesToExclude))
        {
            clearFolderWithFilter(di.FullName, filesToExclude);
            di.Delete();
        }
    }
```

I need help replacing `folderName = @"C:\A\B"` with `folderName = @"$\A\B"` . Here, `"$"` is something that will search the whole computer and then delete the folder `"B"` after finding it

I am expecting to delete a folder by getting its dynamic path in the string variable without any errors related to the folder access denied issues

Comment: Use [DriveInfo.GetDrives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives?view=net-7.0) or [Directory.GetLogicalDrives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getlogicaldrives?view=net-6.0).

Comment: Use `EnumerationOptions` with `IgnoreInaccessible = true` to avoid access denied.

Comment: See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives?view=netframework-4.8.1) to identify all drives

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try the above ways

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the required answer. Thank you so much for your help, Alexander and Smith.

The code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Hello
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EnumerationOptions opt = new EnumerationOptions();

            DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

            foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
            {
                if (d.IsReady == true)
                {
                    opt.IgnoreInaccessible = true;
                    string result = d.Name + @"A\B";
                    Program.clearFolderWithFilter(result, "dog.txt");
                }
            }

        }

        private static void clearFolderWithFilter(string folderName, string filesToExclude)
        {
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(folderName);

            try
            {

                foreach (FileInfo fi in dir.GetFiles())
                {
                    if (!fi.Name.Contains(filesToExclude))
                    {
                        fi.Delete();
                    }
                }

                foreach (DirectoryInfo di in dir.GetDirectories())
                {
                    if (!di.Name.Contains(filesToExclude))
                    {
                        clearFolderWithFilter(di.FullName, filesToExclude);
                        di.Delete();
                    }

                }

            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // nothing to log
            }

        }


    }
}
```